# Invoking storyboard defined in view when ItemsSource is updated

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvp

I am trying to build some notification control in Silverlight. When I click the notification icon it shows/hides the notification window which contains all notification messages.

I have an `ItemsControl` in *view* whose `ItemsSource` is binded to an ObservableCollection in *presenter*.

**I want to invoke a Storyboard defined in view whenever ItemSource (i.e. ObservableCollection in Presenter) is updated.**

Is it possible with `EventTriggers`? if yes how?

Can I invoke Storyboard from presenter, if yes how? And is it a bad idea to invoke Storyboard from presenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example using an Expression Blend behavior `BeginStoryBoardAction` together with a custom `DataChangedTrigger`: [wp7 listboxitem animation on bound data changes (mvvm)](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/wp7-listboxitem-animation-on-bound-data-changes-mvvm/)

You can still use Blend behaviors even if you don't have Blend, you just need the Blend SDK.